# Write access to folder in wwwroot/ IIS window 7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I am testing an ASP.NET website on local IIS (Windows 7)

I wanted the file uploaded by the user on the webpage to  be saved on the server/folder where the application resides.

I granted read/write permissions to the folder containing the website files in inetpub/wwwroot

But while testing the application, after attaching file and click  submit, the attached file disappears and nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Add the required folder permissions for the NETWORK SERVICE account and see if that works for you?

Comment: Thanks Irish.I granted required permissions to IIS_IUSRS(machine name) and that solved the problem